# NSCursor set not working on unfocused window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscursor

EDIT: I made a small XCode project on GitHub that replicates the issue I'm describing: https://github.com/mdinacci/testnscursor

I have a custom `NSTableCellView` in which I track mouse enter/exit events over a `NSTextField`. When the mouse enter the field, I change the cursor to a pointing hand:

```
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSCursor *cursor = [NSCursor pointingHandCursor];
    [cursor set];
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSCursor *cursor = [NSCursor arrowCursor];
    [cursor set];
}
```

The table is displayed inside an `NSPopover` and the code above works beautifully when the popover is in focus, but it doesn't when the popover is unfocused. The cell view **does** receive the enter/exit events, but the cursor simply won't update.

Is this a bug ? Any ideas why the cursor won't update when the popover isn't in focus ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple confirmed it's a bug (#2277286) and as far as I know there's no available workaround.